# Realm update Swift unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I am making a simple list app with Realm and I have trouble making update method. This is my code.

**Task.swift**

```
class Task: Object {
    dynamic var id = 0
    dynamic var name = ""
    dynamic var content = ""
    dynamic var createdDate = NSDate()

    override class func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }

    class func autoIncrement() -> Int{
        let realm = try! Realm()
        let TaskList = realm.objects(Task.self).sorted(byKeyPath: "id", ascending: true)
        let Last = TaskList.last
        if TaskList.count == 0{
            return 0
        } else{
            return Last!.id + 1
        }
}
```

}

**TaskController.swift**

```
static func updateTask(name:String, content:String, oldTask:Task){
    RealmController.updateTask(name:name, content:content, task: oldTask)
    //RealmController.getData(taskList: &appDelegate.task)
}
```

**RealmController.swift**

```
static func updateTask(name:String, content:String, task: Task){
    let taskId = task.id
    let RealTask = realm.objects(Task.self).filter("id == %@", taskId).first
    try! realm.write {
            RealTask?.name = name
            RealTask?.content = content
    }
}
```

**error message.**

> 2017-02-10 17:13:57.179 RealmTest1[7156:9710210]
>   -[RealmTest1.EditViewController saveTask:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fd06351eaa0 2017-02-10 17:13:57.183
>   RealmTest1[7156:9710210] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[RealmTest1.EditViewController
>   saveTask:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fd06351eaa0'

**stack trace**

```
0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000107c00d4b __exceptionPreprocess + 171<br/>
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010766221e objc_exception_throw + 48<br/>
2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000107c70f04 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 132
3   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000107b86005 ___forwarding___ + 1013<br/>
4   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000107b85b88 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120<br/>
5   UIKit                               0x00000001080268bc -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 83<br/>
6   UIKit                               0x00000001081acc38 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67<br/>
7   UIKit                               0x00000001081acf51 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 444<br/>
8   UIKit                               0x00000001081abe4d -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 668<br/>
9   UIKit                               0x0000000108094545 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 2747<br/>
10  UIKit                               0x0000000108095c33 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 4011<br/>
11  UIKit                               0x00000001080429ab -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 371<br/>
12  UIKit                               0x000000010882f72d __dispatchPreprocessedEventFromEventQueue + 3248<br/>
13  UIKit                               0x0000000108828463 __handleEventQueue + 4879<br/>
14  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000107ba5761 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17<br/>
15  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000107b8a98c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556<br/>
16  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000107b89e76 __CFRunLoopRun + 918<br/>
17  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000107b89884 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 420<br/>
18  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010d8caa6f GSEventRunModal + 161<br/>
19  UIKit                               0x0000000108024c68 UIApplicationMain + 159<br/>
20  RealmTest1                          0x000000010691518f main + 111<br/>
21  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010a44d68d start + 1<br/>
```

After I restart App, content is already changed.
How can I fix it?

Comment: The error message says that a `-saveTask:` message is being sent to `EditViewController`. Does that class implement that method? You've only showed code for a `updateTask` method.

Answer (score 1):

The stack trace appears to be unrelated to any of the code you've posted. The problem is that `-[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:]` is calling a method on an object which does not implement that object. There are two normal causes for this:

1. You simply passed in the wrong object when registering the touch handler.
2. The object which you registered as the handler has been deallocated, and some unrelated object has been allocated in the same place. Enabling "Zombie Objects" In "Scheme -> Run -> Diagnostics" will make this case fail in a more informative way.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your method

```
static func updateTask(name:String, content:String, task: Task){
let taskId = task.id
let RealTask = realm.objects(Task.self).filter("id == %@", taskId).first
try! realm.write {
        RealTask?.name = name
        RealTask?.content = content
}
}
```

to

```
static func updateTask(name:String, content:String, task: Task){
let taskId = task.id
if let RealTask = realm.objects(Task.self).filter("id == %@", taskId).first {
 try! realm.write {
        RealTask.name = name
        RealTask.content = content
}}
}
```